# Font change after image display while export to PDF in Jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I created a jupyter notebook and I have used the following code. After that I added a markdown text. It display ok in jupyter but when export it to *PDF* the text after the image changed its font.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(urlopen("https://liquipedia.net/commons/images/e/e9/Dgondi.jpg"))
img
```

And then the text in a *markdown* block:

```
This is a test
```

The text below is displayed with a code font rather than a normal font.

You can view the image [here](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502791507345)

The notebook can be download it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12EuJ6rz9TPVQ1ROLnlzk9Ue-dp2j6WTP)

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue. It seems like using the Image function causes all font afterwards to switch to a code font. This seems to be a bug. A workaround I've found is rather than using a code block to display images, use a markdown block. For example, rather than use the following to display an image (in a code block):

```
Image("Images/MVC.png")
```

Use the following in a markdown block:

```
![title](Images/MVC.png)
```

Using this eliminated the bug. Let me know if this helps.